# Trying to Install BeauttifulSoup 'bs4' does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am getting the following error when attempting to isntall BeautifulSoup4. 
error: package directory 'bs4' does not exist

Here is a print how I am attempting to run the setup.

```
C:\Python27>python C:\Users\martinbshp\Downloads\beautifulsoup4-
4.1.0\setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'bs4' does not exist
```

There is a setup.py file inside the beautifulsoup4-4.1.0 folder as well as a bs4 subfolder. What am I missing? BTW, I cannot run pip or any method that needs to go out to the internet to pull packages from this computer Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `cd C:\Users\martinbshp\Downloads\beautifulsoup4-
4.1.0`  and `python setup.py install` ?

Comment: Thank you that worked. I cd into the BS folder and from there it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup 4 is published through PyPi, so if you can’t install it with the system packager, you can install it with easy_install or pip. The package name is beautifulsoup4, and the same package works on Python 2 and Python 3.

```
$ easy_install beautifulsoup4

$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

(The BeautifulSoup package is probably not what you want. That’s the previous major release, Beautiful Soup 3. Lots of software uses BS3, so it’s still available, but if you’re writing new code you should install beautifulsoup4.)

**please try use pip before you download and use setup to install**

Comment: By the looks of things he's on windows.